# float, double and int math in Java

Tags: java, math, floating-point, int, double

I had some doubts/questions about the math in Java, so I made a small program a screenshot of which you can see in this link:
http://www.imageshuffle.com/view.php?filename=73doublevsfloat.jpg
How are such numbers even possible?

`f / i` should be `0.0155` no matter how you look at it
`i * f` should be `155` no matter how you look at it
`i + f` should be `101.55`
`i - f` should be `98.45`

etc. Same with double.
So what gives? Why is math in Java so incorrect?

Comment: *"Why is math in Java so incorrect?"* When in doubt, blame Java :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because `i /= f` modifies `i`: it's equivalent of `i = i / f` (plus rounding).
Thus, when you execute `f / i`, `i` is ~65 instead of 100.